# Strange Z-index issue with IE9 and IE10?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, z-index, internet-explorer-10

I have got a strange issue with my calendar on IE9 and IE10. The issue is related to z-index. Here is the url of the [site](http://www.latgalesgors.lv/en). When you see the piano calendar in Ie9 and IE 10, on the first attempt it shows fine. But when you scroll up and down the borders of the dates disappears. If I remove the z-index then it shows fine but then I am not able to see the event dates on the calendar. I would be really grateful to you all if you help me in fixing this issue. I have been trying very hard to get it fixed.

To make it more clear, I am attaching 2 screenshots, the right one and the distorted one after mouse scroll in IE9 and IE10.
[image]
[image]

Comment: It will look fine in the first instance. Scroll the page up and down 1 or 2 times then you see the borders of the piano getting disappeared.

Comment: As I said, it looks fine to me.

Comment: I have updated my question and attached screenshots for more clarity. Thanks.

Comment: First, validate your code with http://validator.w3.org/check. You`ll notice 28 errors (as I did). Fix them and the things may get improved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try not to use z-index: -1;

```
header .header-calendar-block ul.event-calendar li.day span.day-bg - change z-index: 1;

header .header-calendar-block ul.event-calendar li.day .row-calendar-event-day, header .header-calendar-block ul.event-calendar li.day .day-has-event - add position: relative; z-index: 2;

header .header-calendar-block ul.event-calendar li.day span.day-off-bg - add z-index: 2;
```

maybe this helps